# figuring out action performed based on date column for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id         sms_sent_date       sms_number      Action_date              action_performed
A           21-11-2021             1            21-11-2021                 opened
A           22-11-2021             2            22-11-2021                 clicked
A           23-11-2021             3            23-11-2021                 opened
A           23-11-2021             3            23-11-2021                 proceeded
A           23-11-2021             3            23-11-2021                 halted
B           11-12-2021             1            11-12-2021                 opened
B           12-12-2021             2            12-12-2021                 opened
B           12-12-2021             2            12-12-2021                 clicked
B           12-12-2021             2            12-12-2021                 succeded
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id         sms_sent_date       sms_number      Action_date              action_performed
A           23-11-2021             3            23-11-2021                 opened
B           12-12-2021             2            12-12-2021                 opened
```

I am trying to find out , what was the initial Action_date and first action_performed on the last sms_sent_date for each user

I know with this code `sms_max = df.groupby(['Id']).agg({'sms_sent_date ': [np.max]})`
i can get the last sms sent date , but how to fetch the respective info from other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter rows by maximal `sms_sent_date` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and then get first row by `Id` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df[df['sms_sent_date'].eq(df.groupby(['Id'])['sms_sent_date'].transform('max'))]
         .drop_duplicates('Id'))
print (df1)
  Id sms_sent_date  sms_number Action_date action_performed
2  A    23-11-2021           3  23-11-2021           opened
6  B    12-12-2021           2  12-12-2021           opened
```